# How to fix/freeze theme color of a shape in google slide using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to freeze the shape color in google slide. So, if the user changes the theme, the shape color should not change. I understand google sheet support Theme and RGB type. I am using below snippet to fix the RGB color.

```
if (pageElements[j].getPageElementType() == "SHAPE") {
        var fill = pageElements[j].asShape().getFill().getSolidFill().getColor();
        var colorType = fill.getColorType();

        Logger.log(colorType)
        if (colorType == "RGB") {
          shapeColor = fill.asRgbColor().asHexString();
          Logger.log(shapeColor)
          pageElements[j].asShape().getFill().setSolidFill(shapeColor)
        }
        else if (colorType == "THEME") {
          shapeColor = fill.asThemeColor().getThemeColorType();
          Logger.log(shapeColor)

pageElements[j].asShape().getFill().setSolidFill(shapeColor)
        }
      }
```

Is there a way we can set/fix the theme color of the shape
[Google Slide Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/theme-color#getthemecolortype)

Comment: I would like to understand the question better. Is the end goal to get the theme color of the shape and set it as an RGB color to prevent it from changing when choosing a different theme?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getConcreteColor()` to get the RGB color based on the theme that is currently selected.

### Try this:

```
else if (colorType == "THEME") {
  shapeColor = fill.asThemeColor().getThemeColorType();
  // Using the theme in the slide that contains the shape:
  shapeColor = pageElements[j].getParentPage().getColorScheme().getConcreteColor(shapeColor).asRgbColor().asHexString();

  // Using the theme of a specific slide previously stored in a ${slide} variable
  // shapeColor = slide.getColorScheme().getConcreteColor(shapeColor).asRgbColor().asHexString();

  Logger.log(shapeColor);
  pageElements[j].asShape().getFill().setSolidFill(shapeColor)
}
```

---

#### Reference:

- [ColorScheme class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color-scheme).